# Check and insert a value inside a array(vector) of structs

Tags: c, vector, struct

So, I'm trying to add an element to my vector of a struct. I ask the user for the data to add but, before I add it, I need to check if 2 of those 3 members are between some values. I have to function to do this but, when I run the program, the members that are checked, are "asked" twice. Once when they are checked and then when they are added to the vector. What I want is them to be added only if they pass the validation function. Here is my code:

I.E:
Input: 2160482 20 Nelson ( this will pass the validate function but, the way my code is done, I have to do so twice for "Numero" and "notaFinal").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIMITE 31
#define MAX_ALUNOS 60
//#define limite_inferior 2150001
//define limite_superior 2169999

typedef struct
{
    int numero;
    int notaFinal;
    char nome[LIMITE];
} tEstudante;

//tEstudante ler_dados_estudante(void);
int validar_insert (int minimo, int maximo);
int ler_dados_estudante(tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS], int numAlunos);
void mostrar_dados_estudante(tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS], int numAlunos);
void alterar_dados_aluno (tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS], int numAlunos);
int procurar_aluno(tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS], int numAlunos, int numero_aluno);
int menu();

void main(void)
{
    tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS];

    int numAlunos;
    int option;
    // int numero;
    // int nota;
    // char nome;

    option = menu();

    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Inserir dados\n");
        ler_dados_estudante(vAlunos, numAlunos);
        //nome = validar_insert();
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Mostrar dados dos estudantes");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Alterar notas finais dos estudantes");
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Estatisticas das avaliacoes");
        break;

    case 5:
        printf("Gravar dados em ficheiro");
        break;

    case 6:
        printf("Ler dados do ficheiro");
        break;

    case 0:
        printf("Sair");
        break;
    }
}

int menu ()
{
    int opcao;

    do
    {
        printf("1 - Inserir dados do estudante");
        printf("\n2 - Mostrar dados dos destudantes");
        printf("\n3 - Alterar notas finais do estudantes");
        printf("\n4 - Estatisticas das avaliacoes");
        printf("\n5 - Gravar dados em ficheiro");
        printf("\n6 - Ler dados de ficheiro");
        printf("\n0 - Fim\n");

        printf("Escolha uma opcao:\n");
        scanf("%i", &opcao);

        if (opcao != 1 && opcao != 2 && opcao != 3 && opcao != 4 && opcao != 5 && opcao != 6 && opcao != 0)
            printf("Opcao invalida !\n\n");
    }
    while (opcao != 1 && opcao != 2 && opcao != 3 && opcao != 4 && opcao != 5 && opcao != 6 && opcao != 0);

    return opcao;
}

int validar_insert (int minimo, int maximo)
{
    int valor;

    do
    {
        scanf("%i", &valor);
        if (valor < minimo || valor > maximo)
        {
            printf("Valor fora do intervalo aceitavel");
            printf("\nInserir dados novamente: \n");
        }

        else
            return valor;
    }
    while (valor < minimo || valor > maximo);
}


int ler_dados_estudante(tEstudante vAlunos[MAX_ALUNOS], int numAlunos)
{

    int numero;
    int nota;
    char nome;

    printf("Insira o numero do aluno: \n");
    numero = validar_insert (2150001, 2169999);
    vAlunos[1].numero = numero;

    printf("Insira a nota final do aluno: \n");
    nota = validar_insert (0, 20);
    vAlunos[1].notaFinal = nota;

    printf("Insira o nome do aluno: \n");
    scanf(" %s", &vAlunos[1].nome);
    //scanf("%i %i %s", &vAlunos[1].numero, &vAlunos[1].notaFinal, &vAlunos[1].nome);

    printf("%i %i %s", vAlunos[1].numero, vAlunos[1].notaFinal, vAlunos[1].nome);

}
```

Comment: Missing code is not good. We need a [mcve] so as not to waste time clarifying the exact context of the code. Also, please provide the input, the expected output and the exact actual output.

Comment: Code in English (function names, variable names, string literals and comments) might make it easier on most of the users here to read, thus increasing your chances to actually get an answer.

Comment: You are not doing the basic checking essential of external input, which may not be what you expect. Always check the return value from the `scanf` family - number of arguments converted. Also arguments for `%s` do not need to have the `&`. So for example `if(scanf("%s", vAlunos[1].nome) != 1) { /* evasive action */ }`

Comment: I add  the rest of my code, thanks

Comment: In `main` the variable `int numAlunos;` is uninitilaised so `ler_dados_estudante(vAlunos, numAlunos);` invokes *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @WeatherVane True. Though it should be noted that that variable is never actually used.

Comment: The code runs with no errors, and yes I didnt use that viarable yet. But I can run the code, I have the menu and, when I choose the 1st submenu, it asks for the data to add. Here it is the output [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18019794/Screenshot%202016-12-25%2020.56.12.png)

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand the code due to it not being in English. But it seems the problem is because you have a `scanf` within `validar_insert` which reads and validates the value but it is not stored. Then of course you need to read it again in `ler_dados_estudante` to store the value.

Comment: @kaylum yeah you are right,  I guess it was missing that part. I'll add that to my code in the post.

Comment: Now your edit has made the question confusing. Does what you have changed fix the original problem? If not, then what exactly is the problem now?

Comment: @kaylum yes it fixed the problem